# Replace wysiwyg html tokens in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a response from server like this:

{ text: "Lorem Ipsum is **%var1%** dummy text of the **%vat2%** and typesetting industry." }

How I can replace string betwin %% with variables in react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a React specific question but more of a javascript one.
Have a look at the [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function which, in your case allows you to do something like this:

```js
const template = 'Lorem Ipsum %var1% lorem ipsum';
const value = 'TEST TEST 1234';

const str = template.replace('%var1%', value);
console.log(str);
```

Comment: This is an often-posted duplicate. It doesn't need more answers. :-)